# How to implement a secure video streaming website?

Tags: files

I want to create a secure Video streaming website where people need to pay to play videos and they should not be able to download directly the video.
What are the possible solution to achieve this? I know there is a flowplayer secure streaming plugin http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/secure.html but is this enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a complicated problem with a lot of possible approaches; a whole book could be written about it (your question is probably too broad).

That said, have you checked out [Videola](http://videola.tv/)?  Videola is a Drupal-based distribution for creating subscription-based websites.  It's made by [Lullabot](https://www.lullabot.com/), one of the leading Drupal companies, and they use it to power their learning network, [Drupalize.me](http://drupalize.me/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have checked videola and it has almost all features I need.

Answer (score 1):

All of the solutions that I have seen so far recommended provide protection of the links to the resource, but nothing to prevent users from screen recording the video as it is played. For that you can add protection to the page displaying the video by using [**Copysafe Web Protection**](http://www.artistscope.com/copysafe_web_protection.asp).

Copysafe Web provides an easy to use and economical solution that can be used in all popular Windows browsers, but if you want absolutely unexploitable protection for web media you can try the [**ArtistScope Site Protection System**](http://www.artistscope.com/artis-secure-web-reader.asp) (ASPS). ASPS is most secure because it uses a custom web browser specially designed to protect web media instead of expose it. The ASPS site filter can be applied to any web site on Apache and Windows servers, including Wordpress, Joomla and Drupal portal solutions.

Answer (score 0):

the security that in that article you posted is only "security by obscurity", because the shared secret needs to be passed to the client, who can easily decompile it from the swf file. The [security flow](http://wowzatoolbox.com/securetoken-mechanism) is basically here. It's interesting why do the docs say that having that key hardcoded and compiled into the swf is safe. Having the key in his hands, nothing prevents him from compiling his own player.

I suggest you that you implement your own authentication mechanism based on Wowza Server Side API, for example you can create something similar to [Wowza Wrench](http://wowzatoolbox.com/wrench), which comes with pay per minute for Wowza by the way. If you want to prevent Wrench tokens from being compromised before usage, you need to use transport level security, e.g. use HTTPS for your website. They have a Drupal Wowza integration article there on the site.